# Reload screen when the tab is changed or tab is pressed twice in react navigation 2?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabbar

I have 3 tabs in my project

- Home
- Bookmarks
- Random

Now I want to reload (fetch data) when i change the tab from either **home** to **bookmarks** or **random** or vice versa.

I could only call them once ie first visit as i have been calling the API from `componentDidMount().` I was trying with `willFocus` listener events but couldn't able to use it.

**How to reset data and load screen once tab is switched or pressed twice?**

Any lead would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to pass `tabBarOnPress` prop to your tab navigator where you can fetch your data and then call the `defaultHandler`: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#tabbaronpress

Comment: I tried this way but data populates from previous state not reset . What to do to restart whole state at initial level when tab changed. FYI data fetching from api (component did mount lifecycle) Thanks in advance.